# android.content.pm.PackageManager $NameNotFoundException com.google.android.webview React Native

Tags: android, react-native, android-webview, apk

This application was working just fine before attempting to create an apk file. I created a signed keystore and tried to generate an apk file but that apk crashes and now when I try to run it in physical device it gives this error. I am unable to understand what sort of error this is. Can anyone help me guide through this?
I am attaching the screenshot as well as my androidxml file.[image: <code>Error</code>]
[image: errorlog]

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

package="com.***">

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />

  <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </service>
  <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseInstanceIdService">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </service>

  <service android:name="io.invertase.firebase.messaging.RNFirebaseBackgroundMessagingService" />


  <meta-data
    android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
    android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id"/>


  <meta-data
```

android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
   android:value="****"/>

```
  <receiver android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationReceiver"/>
  <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"  android:name="io.invertase.firebase.notifications.RNFirebaseNotificationsRebootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
      <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
</application>
```

Comment: are you using any webview? and post the error log too

Comment: No I am not, where can I find errorlog?

Comment: via adblogcat..

Comment: It says chromium WebView package does not exist, I don't know where this error is situated exactly